# Resharper Not Detecting Custom Plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm trying to build a very simple resharper plugin. The intent is that we can share our internal coding standards as a nuget package. I'm targeting Resharper 2016.2.2

The nuspec file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>Purplebricks.Standards</id>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
    <title>Purplebricks Coding Standards</title>
    <authors>Rob White</authors>
    <owners>Purplebricks</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://www.purplebricks.com</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Team settings and live templates for ReSharper</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © Purplebricks</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Wave" version="[2.0]" />
    </dependencies>
    <releaseNotes>
    </releaseNotes>
    <tags>settings</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Settings\" target="DotFiles\Extensions\Purplebricks.Standards\settings\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

When the package is created the `.dotsettings` file is in the nuspec file on the path `<Package Root>\DotFiles\Extensions\Purplebricks.Standards\settings\Standards.DotSettings`

The resulting package is copied to `X:\resharper\Purplebricks.Standards.0.4.0.nupkg`, resharper has an additional extension manager package source of `x:\resharper`

So far as I can tell everything is wired up correctly, but the extension never shows in the resharper extension manager. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The issue is the dependency on `Wave`, I should be using `<dependency id="Wave" version="[6.0]" />`, which is detailed here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Extensions/PlatformVersioning.html